# Bash script set Coordinate Universal Time on remote system using ssh and date

Tags: bash, date, ssh, shellcheck

I have a bash script that attempts to synchronize the time on another machine.  It is not my source code, but as I am refactoring bash script, I am trying to get it to pass ShellCheck.

The source code for it looks something like this:

`d=$(date -u +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S)
ssh decs@host-zc1 "sudo date -u ${d}"`

The **ShellCheck** warning is **SC2029** and states "Note that, unescaped, this expands on the client side.".  In fact I don't want to escape this.

Is there another way to get rid of this warning and yet perform this step?

Answer (score 0):

When you've determined that a warning does not apply to you, you can ignore it with a `# shellcheck disable` comment:

```
d=$(date -u +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S)
# shellcheck disable=SC2029
ssh decs@host-zc1 "sudo date -u ${d@Q}"
```

Though you should really be using `${d@Q}` or `printf %q` to ensure the name will be properly escaped.

Comment: Can you give the ```${d@Q}``` and/or ```printf %q``` as the example solution.  I'd really like to avoid disabling the ShellCheck warning.  There is a reason why it is coming up as a warning.

Comment: @Kris You're get an info level message whose [wiki page](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2029) says "If you do want your string expanded on the client side, you can safely ignore this message". Presumably there are just a lot of cases of people writing `ssh host "echo $HOSTNAME"` and being confused. There does not appear to be a workaround without a comment, which is really too bad.

Comment: Yep, I was looking at the ***Exception*** section at the link:
https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2029

Anyway, I will look at writing it a different way.  I just didn't understand what ```${d@Q}``` mean and what it would do exactly.